# Laravel 4 with ajax serialize, submit with check box

Tags: jquery, laravel-4

I'm Develop a Student Information System using Laravel. I used JQuery Ajax to CURD Operations

I'm with stuck with the problem. how to send check-box values to controller class (the form contain 20 different inputs so it hard to filter via javascript).I use isset method but wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for example, you can use checkbox value='1' i.e. boolean in database. So when you uncheck checkbox and submit the form the controller does not get the checkbox value in controller, in that case you can use

```
$physics= Input::get('physics');
empty($physics) ? $physics = 0 : $physics = 1;
$ModelObject->physics = $physics;
```

This may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
if(Input::has('inputname')) {
Input::get('inputname');
 };
```

Comment: i found solution. i use array_key_exists() method